# HTML5 create field which hides the Text, but can be copy/pasted

Tags: html, password-protection

I would like to add a field to my HTML5 application in which I can write passwords and when saved, the password will be masked with ****.
So that when accessing the page together with a customer, he cannot see the password, but I need to be able to copy it. So a "Show PW" button to copy it wouldn't work.

Is there a way to do that?
I sadly didn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is make an onclick function on the button and

```
<!-- The text field -->
<!- The value passed is for just testing user will enter the password -->
<input type="password" value="Hello World" id="myInput">

<!-- The button used to copy the text -->
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

MyFunction() will be then

```
function myFunction() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

I hope it helps.

Comment: Comments are added so you can grasp what is happening

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution I thought off as well. But I would prefere being able to normaly copy/paste the text without a button, as the layout doesn't really fit a button anymore. I have once seen this implemented, but I forgot where. Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean by the key combination Ctrl + c to copy the text from the input field?

Comment: Exactly. Ctrl C on the field

Comment: Ok, so I researched a bit and unfortunaly there is no way to copy the password field but are some tricks we can use. Are you the only one who is going to password, then the trick will be somewhat useful but if others are gonna be using this feature/functionality then it's not possible as our browsers don't allow copy pasting input password fields

Comment: Hmm okay. No it's a company wide thing. I'll see if we'll manage to cram a button in there. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The Rattic implements this function using text-shadow css property.

Create a css class like this:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;
```

When you want to hide the password, add this class. Add a button to copy the content from the field.

The result will be like this:

[image: screenshot; result]

It might be a little different from what you try to implement, but has the same idea to hide the password and give the ability to copy it.

If you want to use * instead of text-shadow, I think you need to make the field a control component, save the password but show the * according to the length of the password.

It will be like:

```
password = input 
display = strings.repeat('*', password.length);
```

The password can only be accessed by the button, and you display the * in the field. That needs some knowledge about states of components. You can choose the one you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Just create button with data-pass property and hidden by css input. Then, as explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp) copy text from created input to clipboard.